# Updating Eclipse Luna and Android SDK shows : "Updating Software" Has encountered a

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-luna

I tried to update the **Android SDK** and it shows up the error:

> **"Updating Software" Has encountered a problem"**

Same for **" Check for Updates"** and **"Install New Softwares"**, I get the same problem, I've did some searchs and I found that I need to change the site to **HTTP** instead of **HTTPS** but I got the same error. 
Here it's in details:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,23.0.4.1468518 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,23.0.4.1468518 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,23.0.4.1468518 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,23.0.4.1468518 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,23.0.4.1468518 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,23.0.4.1468518 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,23.0.4.1468518 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.aether.maven,3.1.0.v20140706-2237 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt,8.5.0.201409172108 No repository found
>   containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers,3.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers.ui,3.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core,3.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx,3.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui,3.2.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui.cxx,3.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core,5.8.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.native,5.7.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32,5.4.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64,5.3.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core,7.5.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core,7.3.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.ui,6.2.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui,7.5.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user,5.3.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf,2.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb,4.5.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui,2.4.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui,2.4.100.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb,7.0.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.ui,7.0.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.launch,7.1.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.make.core,7.3.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui,7.2.0.201409172108 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core,8.3.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui,8.3.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui,8.2.2.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.ui,5.8.1.201409172108 No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.4.100.v20140925-0400 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.101.201408150207 No repository
>   found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf,3.4.0.v20140827-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer,5.0.0.v20140827-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.identity,3.4.0.v20140827-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer,3.2.200.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl,1.0.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl,1.0.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.ssl,1.1.0.v20140827-1444 No repository
>   found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,3.4.1.201406201815-r No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,3.4.1.201406201815-r No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,3.4.1.201406201815-r No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.9.0.v20140901-1055 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.3.0.v20140901-1055 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.9.0.v20140901-1055 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.10.1.v20140901-1055 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.3.1.v20140820-1706 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui,1.3.1.v20140820-1706 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui,1.3.1.v20140908-1651 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.package.java,4.4.1.20140925-1820 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.100.201408150207 No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core,3.13.0.v20140830-0030 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui,3.13.0.v20140809-1218 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2228 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui,1.5.0.v20140830-1416 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.13.0.v20140704-2323 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.13.0.v20140702-2155 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core,1.5.0.v20140905-0008
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui,1.5.0.v20140826-1731
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.13.0.v20140702-2155
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.13.0.v20140704-2323 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.13.0.v20140702-2155
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc,3.13.0.v20140702-2155 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.tasks.ui,3.13.0.v20140819-2236
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.cvs.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2223 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.debug.ui,3.13.0.v20140814-1721 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core,3.13.0.v20140702-2155 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui,3.13.0.v20140820-1854 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2223 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.ui,1.5.0.v20140702-2223 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui,3.13.0.v20140704-0050 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2228 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.ui,1.5.0.v20140702-2228 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ant,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks,3.13.0.v20140819-2236 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.core,3.13.0.v20140702-2155 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2155 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.resources.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs,3.13.0.v20140704-0050 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core,3.13.0.v20140704-0050 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.core,3.13.0.v20140704-0050
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.ui,3.13.0.v20140704-0050 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search,3.13.0.v20140704-0050 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui,3.13.0.v20140826-1734 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.cvs,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui,3.13.0.v20140702-2225 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.core,1.5.0.v20140702-2223 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.ui,1.5.0.v20140702-2223 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.core,2.2.0.v20140905-1454
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.ui,2.2.0.v20140702-2138
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.context.ui,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core,2.2.0.v20140905-1515 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.ant,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.osgi,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui,2.2.0.v20140902-2320 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core,2.2.0.v20140905-1515
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.core,2.2.0.v20140903-1442
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.ui,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki.core,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki.ui,2.2.0.v20140702-2138
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.core,2.2.0.v20140905-1454
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.ui,2.2.0.v20140702-2138
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki.core,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki.ui,2.2.0.v20140702-2138
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki.core,2.2.0.v20140902-2320
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki.ui,2.2.0.v20140702-2138
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui,2.2.0.v20140902-2320 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.apidocs,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.apidocs.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.calls,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.calls.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.chain.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.injection,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes.io,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.models,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.overrides,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.overrides.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.subwords.rcp,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.utils,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.200.v201304241450 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.infopop,1.0.300.v201309101952 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.401.v201408132036 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets,1.2.200.v201208080420 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.core,1.1.700.v201211012112 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop,1.0.400.v201309112106 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtdeditor.doc.user,1.0.700.v201208081537
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache,1.0.700.v201211211430 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user,1.1.100.v201208081537 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.300.v201406172023 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop,1.0.300.v201309112106 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.infopop,1.0.300.v201309101952
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.901.v201408131505 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.infopop,1.0.400.v201309112106 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user,1.0.700.v201208081537
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui,1.2.500.v201208081537 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsdeditor.doc.user,1.0.800.v201208081537
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd,2.10.0.v20140901-1055 No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xsd.edit,2.7.0.v20140901-1055 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature,23.0.4.1468518
>   No repository found containing:
>   binary,epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,4.4.1.20140925-1820
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt,8.5.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb,8.5.0.201409172108 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build,8.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug,8.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf,8.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.native,8.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.platform,8.5.0.201409172108
>   No repository found containing:
>   binary,org.eclipse.cdt_root,8.5.0.201409172108 No repository found
>   containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cvs,1.4.100.v20140925-0400 No
>   repository found containing:
>   binary,org.eclipse.cvs_root,1.4.100.v20140925-0400 No repository found
>   containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature,1.1.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature,3.9.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20140827-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,3.4.1.201406201815-r
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.mpc,1.3.1.v20140908-1651 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature,4.4.1.20140925-1820
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature,4.4.1.20140925-1820
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.200.v201404021757 No repository
>   found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,3.4.1.201406201815-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature,3.13.0.v20140830-0030
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds,1.5.0.v20140830-1416
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.13.0.v20140704-2323
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,1.5.0.v20140905-0008
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http,1.5.0.v20140702-2248
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature,3.13.0.v20140819-2236
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.cvs,1.5.0.v20140702-2223
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery,3.13.0.v20140820-1854
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.git,1.5.0.v20140702-2223
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson,1.5.0.v20140702-2228
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature,3.13.0.v20140702-2225
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature,3.13.0.v20140819-2236
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor,3.13.0.v20140702-2155
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ide,3.13.0.v20140704-0050
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature,3.13.0.v20140702-2225
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions,1.5.0.v20140702-2223
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature,2.2.0.v20140905-1515
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature,3.13.0.v20140826-1734
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.recommenders.net,2.1.9.v20140917-1240 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature,2.1.9.v20140917-1240
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908251833 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.200.v201301161645 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.101.v201107081800
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181831
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.300.v201401292051
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.201.v201208241542
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.ui,1.1.500.v200911182011 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.100.v201305141634
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.6.1.v201408132036
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.6.1.v201409111444
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui,1.0.801.v201308100602 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.900.v201401092025 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas,1.0.700.v201304171715 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.501.v201304022101 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.500.v201310231452 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.6.1.v201409111852
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.6.1.v201409111852
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_userdoc.feature,3.6.0.v201405062147
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core,1.1.900.v201401141857

Comment: It suddenly worked ._. !

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on Juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using older version of eclipse to install ADT Plugin, Please check the Eclipse requirement for ADT.I am sure this is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed my ADT on Eclipse Juno by change from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/ to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/

Answer (score 2):

Change the link to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ will do...

Answer (score 1):

On Luna:

Go to Eclipse Market place, search for ADT and install **Android Development Tools for Eclipse**.

Then GAE from https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4 using the **Install New Software** features will install properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide us the url link you are using to install?There are different kind of links URL , make sure you find the right one.

Comment: If it still does not work you can try https instead http. I looked at the documentation and below the link there is note to add https.Reference http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the leatest version of Eclipse, I mentionned that I've tried to change HTTP and HTTPS and it didn't work. 
I didn't do anything else, then it suddenly worked lol. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

After trying switching http/https protocols on Luna (it didn't work) , went to Help > Install new software. Selected the 'Available Software Sites' preferences, and 'Reloaded' both https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/ . Problem fixed!